# Passing dynamic parameters to CMD and saving the command

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, vbscript, autohotkey

I would like to password-encrypt folders (and ideally also files — individual and multiple ones) pre-selected in the Windows 10 file explorer via the context menu. Unfortunately I couldn't find any program capable of it. If by chance you know one please do tell, that would be the perfect solution.

Otherwise, [this tool](https://www.2brightsparks.com/onclick/help/) is the closest to the described requirements that  I could find. However, it requires to navigate to the desired folder manually via their own navigation window, so it doesn't work just by right clicking a folder in the Windows file explorer. But I have an idea for a workaround: that tool supports the CMD command line so that a folder could be encrypted like so:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\EncryptOnClick\EncryptOnClick.exe" -p password -e "C:\Users\username\Documents\Test"
```

If I could make `password` and the `Test`-folder dynamic variables and store the CMD-command or make it a batch-, AHK-, VBscript-, Powershell- or whatever script I could attach that script to the [registry key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell key as described here](https://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/), right, and it would appear in the context menu upon right-clicking a folder in the file explorer.

But how do I make `password` (and I should be prompted to input one of my choice) and the `Test`-folder (which I already right-clicked in the file explorer) dynamic variables and store that whole thing as a script that I can attach to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell, so that the script appears in the context menu?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `call /?` for how parameters are handled. Use `set /p` to get user input (if you don't like the big black box for input, you have to switch to another language (or use the help of one); `cmd` is command line based):

```
@echo off
set /p "pass=Enter password: "
"C:\Program Files (x86)\EncryptOnClick\EncryptOnClick.exe" -p %pass% -e "%~1"
```

Put a shortcut to that script in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\`

Comment: Many thanks! First I thought it didn't work, but it does in combination with ' "C:\Users\username\Documents\Encrypt.bat" %1" ' entered as key into the registry (with Encrypt.bat including your code).

Answer (score 0):

Without trying it out myself, I'm pretty confident you can do it with AHK as easily as this:

```
;the folder/file path should be here
path := A_Args[1]
InputBox, pass, % "Encrypt File/Folder", % "Enter a password", HIDE
command := """C:\Program Files (x86)\EncryptOnClick\EncryptOnClick.exe"" -p """ pass """ -e """ path """"

;verify that the command we're about to launch is correct
;obviously you'd remove this from the real final version of the script
MsgBox, 4, % "Check command", % "Is this command correct?`n" command
IfMsgBox, Yes
    Run, % command
```

Added a test messagebox in there so you can see if it works as expected.
Related documentation links:
[A_Args](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Args), [InputBox](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InputBox.htm), [Escaping quotes](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/EscapeChar.htm) and [MsgBox](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MsgBox.htm)